# add div using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is supposed to be looping and adding multiple divs, but it isn't working. When I click it, only one div appears. If I click again, nothing happens.

```
<body>
    <div class="start" >
        <div id = "coba">
        </div>

        <div id = "cobi">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var divs = document.getElementById("coba").addEventListener("click", function () {

            for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                var di = document.createElement('div');
                document.getElementById('coba').appendChild(di);

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is working fine Check [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/227u9dpp/)

Comment: Without any styling or content you won't visually see the multiple div elements as they are empty and take up no vertical space

Comment: Can confirm what @PatrickEvans is saying; I tinkered with your code at jsfiddle here: [https://jsfiddle.net/q36tpLfL/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/q36tpLfL/1/). I threw some text in just to be able to see anything, and it looks like it works.

Comment: yeah givem a width and height and a border and see, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you did not do anything with the variable "i" in the for statement. If you look at the fiddles of user2181397 & meghan Armes you will see how they added a line in the script to put it to work.

I tested the below in my IDE and it works just fine:

```
<body>
   <div class="start" style="margin-top:50px; color:black;">
      <div id = "coba">
        <p>Click Me</p>
      </div>

      <div id = "cobi">
      </div>
 </div>

<script>
var divs = document.getElementById("coba").addEventListener("click", function() {

for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
   var di = document.createElement('div');
   di.innerHTML=i;
   document.getElementById('coba').appendChild(di);

}
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but i  have another poblem, so actually i supposed to make fractal tree, and the div shape is rectangular

Comment: the result is like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn0no6aq19nyzw3/Capture.PNG?dl=0 and if i click it again, nothing happens.

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest posting another question for the fractal tree so it can be separate from this one.